# Can I remove ForbiddenRequests and ServerErrors on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When moving some Azure resources from one subscription to another, I noticed a couple of resources that are only visible through the Resource Explorer. They live beneath:

`subscriptions > subscription name > resourceGroups > my resource group > providers > microsoft.insights > alertrules`

The names are `ForbiddenRequests <website name>` and `ServerErrors <website name>`.

I don't have application insights enabled on any of my websites. I also noticed that these resources only exists for my oldest websites and not websites created within the last couple of years.

Can I delete these resources?

Answer (score -1):

Application Gateway
Application Insights
Express Route

are not supported in migration from one azure subscription to another subscription.

Comment: Thanks you for that info. But my question is if I can delete these? I don't want to move them, since I don't know what they do and why they are there.

Comment: insights 's alerts are maily use to inform devops to give attention .